# How to get a ellipse shaped node in Tikz Network?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the excellent [tikz-network](https://github.com/hackl/tikz-network) package written by Jürgen Hackl.
I am trying to change shape of some nodes to be an ellipse, but I can't figure out how to. From the manual, tikz-network:

> With the option *shape* the shape of the vertex can be modified. Thereby the shapes implemented in TikZ can be used, including: circle, rectangle, diamond, trapezium, semicircle, isosceles triangle, ...

But when I compile this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[color=white, x=-1, y=1, label=A]{A}
    \Vertex[color=white, x=1, y=1, label=B, shape=rectangle]{B}
    \Vertex[color=white, x=0, y=0, label=2, shape=ellipse]{2}
    \Edge[lw=1, Direct](A)(2)
    \Edge[lw=1, Direct](B)(2)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

all I get is this

[image: MWE]

while I would expect the shape of node 2 to be an ellipse, not a circle.

Comment: Try use 2222222 instead of 2

Comment: Thank you JouleV. I actually tried this already, down the the number of 2s! ;) but the label just spills over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, your shape is an ellipse. It just happens to be the same height and width, because those are the default settings. You can give extra TikZ options using the `style` option of `\Vertex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[color=white, x=-1, y=1, label=A]{A}
    \Vertex[color=white, x=1, y=1, label=B, shape=rectangle]{B}
    \Vertex[color=white, x=0, y=0, label=2, shape=ellipse, style={minimum width=2cm}]{2}
    \Edge[lw=1, Direct](A)(2)
    \Edge[lw=1, Direct](B)(2)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thanks to your answer I also figured out how to use the regular polygon shape for a vertex: "\Vertex[color=white, x=-1, y=1 shape=regular polygon, style={regular polygon sides=5}, label=A]{A}"

Answer (score 3):

Let me start by spelling out your and and Joule V's observation that the text will just overshoot if is longer than the package expects it to be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[color=white, x=-1, y=1, label=A]{A}
    \Vertex[color=white, x=1, y=1, label=B, shape=rectangle]{B}
    \Vertex[color=white, x=0, y=0, label=2222222, shape=ellipse]{2}
    \Edge[lw=1, Direct](A)(2)
    \Edge[lw=1, Direct](B)(2)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Needless to say that this looks a bit suboptimal. The internal reason why that happens is that the text is not the `node contents`, as one may naively suspect/hope, but, as the label indicates, a `label`. This problem can be solved as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{network x offset/.initial=1ex,network y offset/.initial=1ex,
adjust size/.style={minimum width=width("\vertex@Label")+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/network x offset},
minimum height=height("\vertex@Label")+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/network y offset}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[color=white, x=-1, y=1, label=A]{A}
    \Vertex[color=white, x=1, y=1, label=B, shape=rectangle]{B}
    \tikzset{every label/.append style={}}
    \Vertex[color=white, x=0, y=0, label=2222222, shape=ellipse,
    style={adjust size}]{2}
    \Edge[lw=1, Direct](A)(2)
    \Edge[lw=1, Direct](B)(2)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So all you need to do is to add `style={adjust size}`. As a side effect, this will then really become an ellipse if, as [suggested by JouleV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490003/how-to-get-a-ellipse-shaped-node-in-tikz-network#comment1237298_490003), once you insert a wider (or higher) text. The keys `network x offset` and `network y offset` can be thought of as the analogues of the ordinary pgf keys `inner xsep` and `inner ysep`.